# Problem with Memory storage type in PyQGIS when updating with auto form

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, default

I have a layer of "Memory storage" type (Memory provider) which I
created with Python.

When editing=on and updating values using the attribute table interactively everything works as expected, i.e. the record get's updated.

Then I'm checking "Auto open form" to on. When updating the object interactively using the "Identify Features" tool the auto form opens as expected.

But after saving, I end up with two records sorted to the end, one is the unchanged original and the other record contains the changes (as well as e.g. the same id).

I didn't do anything in my code with the "Identify Features" tool. So this is a bug or at least a very strange default behaviour of PyQGIS.

Any hints?

Comment: Can you specify which version of QGIS you are using.

Comment: QGIS 2.8.1 Wien compiled against Qt 4.8.5 
and QGIS 2.8.2 Wien compiled against Qt 4.8.6

Comment: Can you open a bug report and explicitly mention that it concerns the memory layer. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug and not related to PyQGIS.

It has been [fixed for the 2.10 release](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/commits/master)

Please note that gis.se is not an issue tracker and you should prefer to open a new ticket in the [QGIS issue tracker](http://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/index.html#bugs-features-and-issues).

Comment: Thanks. Opening an issue in the tracker system would have been the next step I would have taken. I was just not sure if it was a "feature" as the answer in this closed issue https://hub.qgis.org/issues/11099 was not clear.

Comment: Glad you pointed the issue out either way :) And to clarify, issue 11099 is unrelated.

Comment: @Stefan are you waiting for more information to be happy to give away the bounty?

Comment: No. Thanks for asking. I thought I already checked it. What I actually still wonder, if there has been an issue in the tracker I have overseen?